# Grails how to call another database table?

Tags: grails, datasource, multiple-databases

Example :
i have 2 db : db1 and db2

and i have 2 domain in my app,

```
class domain1 {
    String test
    Domain2 domain2
    static mapping = {
      datasource 'db1'
    }
}

class domain2 {
   static mapping = {
      datasource 'db2'
   }
}
```

when i try to save class domain1, i get error "an unmapped class"
how to save domain1 class? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a foreign key in one DB referencing something in another DB.
That's why Grails refuses to map such a relation.

Replace your field `Domain2 domain2` by `Integer domain2Id` and control its relation to an object in the `db2` database manually.